# WPF MVVM: Saving Data automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, save

In my WPF MVVM app, I'd like changes to my `Entity Framework` entity classes automatically persisted back to the database. I've had a few ideas about implementing this functionality, but none of them seem optimal.

Here are my current (non-optimal) ideas:

1. Use a `DispatcherTimer`to save changes every interval:

   ```
   DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
   timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
   timer.Tick += (sender, args) => Repository.SaveChanges();
   timer.Start();
   ```
2. Save changes in the program's `OnExit()` method.

   ```
   protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
   {
       Repository.SaveChanges();
       base.OnExit(e);
   }
   ```
3. Save changes every time `OnPropertyChanged()` is called on one of my `Entities`:

   ```
   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
       Repository.SaveChanges();
   }
   ```
4. A combination of **2 & 3**; save the data after counting an arbitrary number of property changes and also save in `OnExit()` to catch any changes that didn't reach the change limit:

   ```
   const int limit = 5;
   int changes = 0;    

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
       if (++changes == limit)
       {
           Repository.SaveChanges();
           changes = 0;
       }
   }
   ```

I assume **1** & **3** are the worst performing out of all of them, and **2** (not 100% sure) won't save any changes if the program crashes. **4** is my preferred option as it balances the amount of saves that are performed.

So, my question is: In your experience or otherwise, what's the best way to approach/tackle this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity: is this a client/server application or is the database stored and accessed locally?

Comment: @BoltClock It's stored and accessed locally.

Comment: I have tried 1,2,4 in my applications and I wouldn't recommend anyone of them. The best solution in my opinion is to have a manual "Save" option as well as a warning if there are unsaved changes when exiting allowing the user to save changes or ignore.

Comment: @Fuji Could you elaborate on why you wouldn't recommend any of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To digress a little; do you also allow a manual way for the user to save? I believe this is important to the question, as it should help determine how stringent you need to be with your auto-save behaviour.

Another consideration; are partial commits allowed? If a user changes one piece of information, the auto-save kicks in, the user changes another piece, and then the app crashes. Is it possible that auto-save could allow data corruption due to the fact that it has saved what was supposed to be an atomic operation that hadn't fully completed?

Now, since you mention that the database is a local one, you don't have to worry too much about the latency of a client-server database. That means that a high frequency of commits should be fine. Therefore, I'd rule out option 2 completely. Saving once on exit seems too risky.

I like the idea of reacting to property changes and saving then, but only if the partial commit consideration above isn't going to be a problem. It will ensure all data is committed on a timely basis.

If the user has a way of manually saving their data, I'd probably go with the timed approach. Set it to 10 seconds (or some value), and fire off the auto-save, with a notification displayed to the user that the auto-save has fired.

The main thing to worry about, I believe, is what the user expects to happen. If you're committing on every change, the user will (probably) not be surprised at the state of their data on a crash. Same goes with the auto-save notification. Informing the user of the save intervals will allow them to shrug off a crash, having confidence that the state of their data will still be relatively fresh.

Comment: Ultimately, the idea of this system is to eliminate the need for manual saving, allowing the user to focus on the task at hand and not worry about the boring stuff. I very much like your idea of alerting the user after performing an autosave.

Comment: Totally understand that, so in your case, I'd go with the property changed method. Though I don't think allowing manual saves, and requiring manual saves are the same thing. If you allow it, go the timed approach, so the user still feels in control of their data when they want to exit the application.

Comment: Decided to offer up two separate views for viewing and editing data. When the user clicks *save*, it provides a nice hook to save the changes made. Cheers for your input!